# Is it possible to forwardSelenium/webdriver results to mechanize/beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, mechanize-python

Ok, so I pretty much used webdriver to navigate to a specific page with a table of results contained in a unique div. I had to use webdriver to fill the forms and interact with the javascript buttons. Anyways, i need to scrape the table into a file but I can't figure this out. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Open Firefox

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html")

# Login and submit

username = driver.find_element_by_id('j_username')
username.send_keys('THE_EMAIL_ADDRESS')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('j_password')
password.send_keys('THE_PASSWORD')

password.submit()

# go to "build a list" url (more like 'build-a-table' get it right guys!

driver.get('http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/search/buildAList.html?_target0=true')

# expand industry list to reveal SIC codes form

el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Industry')]")[0]
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()

# fill sic.codes form with all the SIC codes

siccodes = driver.find_element_by_id('advancedSearchCriteria.sicCodes')
siccodes.send_keys('316998,321114,321211,321212,321213,321214,321219,321911,'
    '321912,321918,321992,322121,322130,326122,326191,326199,327110,327120,'
    '327212,327215,327320,327331,327332,327390,327410,327420,327910,327991,'
    '327993,327999,331313,331315,332216,332311,332312,332321,332322,332323,'
    '333112,333414,333415,333991,'334290,335110,335121,335122,335129,335210,'
    '335221,335222,335224,335228,335311,335312,335912,335929,335931,335932,'
    '335999,337920,339910,339993,339994,339999,423310,423320,423330,423610,'
    '423620,423710,423720,423730,424950,444120')

# wait 5 seconds because this is a big list to load

time.sleep(5)

# Select "Add to List" button and clickity-clickidy-CLICK!

butn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/button')
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(butn, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()

# wait 10 seconds to add them to list

time.sleep(10)

# Now select confirm list button and wait to be forwarded to results page

butn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/input[2]')
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys("\n")
action.move_to_element_with_offset(butn, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()

# wait 10 seconds, let it load and dig up them numbah tables

time.sleep(10)

# Check that we're on the right results landing page...

print driver.current_url

# Good we have arrived! Now lets save this url for scrape-time!

url = driver.current_url

# Print everything... but we only need the table!!! HOWW?!?!?!?

sourcecode = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")

# EVERYTHING AFTER THIS POINT DOESN't WORK!!!! `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

All I need is to print the table out as organized as possible with a for loop but it seems this works a lot better with mechanize or BeautifulSoup. So is this possible? Any suggestions? also, sorry if my code is sloppy, I'm multitasking with deadlines and other scripts. Please help meehh! I will provide my login credentials if you really need them and want to help me. It's nothing too serious, just a company SIC and D-U-N-S number database but I don't think you need it to figure this out. I know there's a few jedi's out there that can save me. :)